Quiero que se muestre contenido a partir de una base de datos
Estoy haciendo una página web de una aerolínea inventada y los usuarios (sin cuenta o con cuenta) pueden comprar un vuelo rellenando un formulario en el que seleccionan el origen, destino y fecha. Todo esto perfecto, pero cuando le dan clic a buscar vuelos, les redirige a la página correcta, pero no se muestran los vuelos disponibles almacenados en la base de datos.
Les proporciono mi código PHP para que me puedan ayudar a buscar la solución:
flights.php:
<?php
include 'connection.php'; 

$origin = $_POST['origin'] ?? '';
$destination = $_POST['destination'] ?? '';
$departureDate = $_POST['departure_date'] ?? '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM Flights WHERE Origin = ? AND Destination = ? AND DepartureDate = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if (!$stmt) {
    die("Error preparing statement: " . $conn->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $origin, $destination, $departureDate);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['flights'] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
} else {
    $_SESSION['flights'] = [];
}
header('Location: ../flights.php');
exit();
?>

Y este es el otro código del archivo HTML convertido a PHP, que es donde se redirige al usuario para que pueda elegir el vuelo que desee y procesar con el pago:
flights.php (archivo html):
<?php
include 'navbar.php';  // Incluye tu barra de navegación si es necesario.

// Asegúrate de iniciar la sesión al comienzo del archivo y verificar correctamente la existencia de datos.
if (!empty($_SESSION['flights'])) {
?>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Calpe Airways Flights</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <style>
            h3 {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .flight-cards {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-around;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .flight-card {
                background-color: #f8f8f8;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 10px;
                width: 250px;
            }

            .flight-date,
            .flight-time,
            .flight-origin,
            .flight-destination,
            .flight-price {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .select-flight-btn {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #0056b3;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .select-flight-btn:hover {
                background-color: #003d7a;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Flights Available</h3>
        <div class="flight-cards">
            <?php foreach ($_SESSION['flights'] as $flight) : ?>
                <div class="flight-card">
                    <div class="flight-date"><?= date('l, F j, Y', strtotime($flight['DepartureDate'])); ?></div>
                    <div class="flight-time"><?= $flight['DepartureTime']; ?></div>
                    <div class="flight-origin"><?= $flight['Origin']; ?></div>
                    <div class="flight-destination"><?= $flight['Destination']; ?></div>
                    <div class="flight-price">$<?= number_format($flight['Price'], 2); ?></div>
                    <a href="purchase.php?flight_id=<?= $flight['FlightID']; ?>" class="select-flight-btn">Select Flight</a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
<?php
} else {
    echo "<p>No flights available.</p>";
}
?>

Edición:
Este es un fragmento del código de como creé la tabla 'flights':
CREATE TABLE Flights (
    FlightID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    AirlineID INT,
    Origin VARCHAR(50),
    Destination VARCHAR(50),
    DepartureDate DATE,
    DepartureTime TIME
);

Adjunto imagen de contenido de la base de datos:

Adjunto foto del formulario que deben rellenar los usuarios. La primera celda es siempre esa opción. La segunda celda les da a elegir entre varios países y la siguiente celda depende de la anterior a esta. He puesto un JavaScript que si seleccionan cualquier otro país que no sea uno en concreto, la siguiente opción será el país al que solo pueden ir (espero que se entienda):

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda que me haga avanzar. Si necesitan que les proporcione algún código en especifico, lo mandaré lo antes posible.
Estoy usando PHP 8.
Gracias.

Buenas, Nacho, bienvenido al sitio. No sé qué versión de PHP estás usando. Puedes editar tu pregunta para añadir esa información. Quizás el problema esté en la llamada a bindParam. En algunas versiones se necesita una llamada a bindParam por cada una de las ? que tengas en la consulta. En tu caso serían 3 llamadas https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php

En muchos casos num_rows puede dar 0 aún cuando haya filas, porque depende del buffer. Considera poner esto: $stmt->store_result();  antes de if ($result->num_rows > 0) { Para más detalles revisa el Manual de PHP. En cualquier caso, preferiría revisar los datos en sí mismos para saber si hay filas, en vez de usar num_rows... Si sigue sin funcionar, comprueba si realmente hay datos que cumplen los criterios de esa consulta, depurando el contenido de las variables $origin, $destination, y $departureDate.

¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna DepartureDate en la Base de datos? Si es un DateTime o un VARCHAR con formato Y-m-d H:i:s, puediera andar por ahí el problema, ya que la búsqueda se está haciendo de forma estricta y por eso no devuelve nada. Edita la pregunta y coloca un ejemplo del contenido de un par de registros de esa tabla y un ejemplo de lo que colocan los usuarios en el formulario.

¿Se presupone que tienes un session_start() tanto en connection.php como en navbar.php?

Hola, @A.Cedano. he aplicado tu solución y me dio errores en un principio pero conseguí arreglarlo, el problema es que los vuelos no aparecen... llevo varios días con este problema y necesito encontrar solución rápida.

@masterguru, no, los usuarios pueden buscar vuelos sin necesidad de tener una sesión iniciada, por eso no tengo puesto el session_start().

¿Y donde crees que se guarda el valor de $_SESSION si no tienes una sesión abierta?  Es decir, al ejecutar el header() estás reinicializando todas las variables globales, incluida $_SESSION, a menos que tengas una sesión abierta.  Intenta usar algun otro sistema de almacenaje en lugar de ese, pues ya ves que no te funciona.

Hola, @aeportugal, he añadido los datos que me pides, agradecería si podrías ayudarme con esa información adicional. Gracias de antemano.

@masterguru, eso era el problema, mi lógica daba por hecho que eso funcionaría, muchísimas gracias.

Yo voto por que primero lo pruebes agregando el session_start() en ambos archivos donde pretendes usar el $_SESSION y mires si funciona. Usar session_start() no implica tener que estar identificado en ninguna parte de tu zona de clientes o usuarios, tan solo te da acceso a esas variables, y para saber si esta bien logeado o no se suele mirar unos valores de $_SESSION predeterminados que tu establezcas y valides, como podria ser user, id, session_id, o como quieras llamarlos en tu script de validación de usuarios.

Perfecto, tenia toda la pinta de ser eso, me alegro. Saludos

@masterguru deberías escribir una respuesta indicando el origen del problema y su solución.

@jachguate Tienes toda la razón del mundo, pero estoy muy perezoso últimamente y me conformo con ayudar en los comentarios y dejar que otros puedan aprovecharlos para elaborar las respuestas completas y detalladas, lo siento.  En este caso deberia ser el propio OP que la elaborara, pues me he basado en suposiciones y el era el que tenia acceso a todo el código.
